# Visual Studio 2015 RTM crashing when opening a Windows Forms

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm facing a rather infuriating issue when trying to open a Windows Forms 'form' on Designer mode.

If I press F7 and go to the aforementioned mode, it shows a Design Time Error

[image]

, and when I click any part of it, VS2015 crashes.

When it suggests me to debug it, (and I grudgingly accept to open another VS 2015 instance, it says that the issue resides on the type initializer from one of it's embedding custom user controls:

[image]
, which is nonsense.

The userControl it complains about has this initializer:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest creating a unit test, NUnit or MS Test, and instantiating that class from that test. This will allow you to set breakpoints and step into the code to debug it. Also, your prime suspect is the inicialiso method. Comment out the call in your constructor to see if it is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedbak, @PaulSasik. I did comment the code, rebuilt it, then went again to the main window designer mode. It still crashed. 
What I noticed, thought, was that when I explicitly removed the UserControl instance from the designer source, and retried to place it, a more detailed error message lead me to the static property in the code.
VS attempted to access it, failed, then crashed. Removed it, then it worked.
Dunno if that serves as an answer, since the bug is still out there.

Comment: Do not open with designer. Step into the call to ListarTiposServicos(). It throws a nullreferenceexception and the exception is unhandled. Find the exception first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Devenv.exe /SafeMode**, it launches the IDE in safe mode loading minimal windows, and check whether it can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is merged recently by using version control software like git, please make sure that the embedded resource file(resx file) of the user control is properly associated. You can correct it in the csproj file.